# open call for artist

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I often see phrases such as "open call for artist", "artist open call", and "artistic open call". I can't figure out what they mean when used colloquially.  Some other phrases connected with 'call' are the following:

"Each call has its own themes ..."

" ... check your call ..."

What does the word 'call' mean here (link to source added)?

> [ARTISTIC OPEN CALL](https://www.florencecontemporary.com/open-call)
>
> Open to artist 18 years and older.  All submitted work must have been created within the last 3 years. Each call has its own themes and mediums accepted, check your call to have more information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both Collins and Dictionary.com, **open call** is defined as

> *an audition, especially for actors or dancers, open to anyone wishing to try out*

[Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/open-call) provides a slightly different meaning (although related)

> *Open call means a local, national or international competition open to professional and amateur artists ...*

Check [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-open-call-audition) here for a similar explanation.

"Open call" is essentially saying that a casting audition, music audition, art exhibition, or any competition is open to public and that there are no restrictions or prerequisites (e.g., no age limits and no requirement of any previous experience), unless explicitly mentioned.

It is important to note that "call" might be used here with a particular meaning. "Call" can mean

> *the fact of people wanting or needing a particular thing. (Collins)*

In your case, the "artistic open call" has an age restriction and a timeline restriction (the art work must have been created within the last 3 years). But within the exhibition/competition, there are two different "calls", which here means "there are two categories". Each "call" or "category" has its own set of restrictions, apart from those the "calls" are open.

In your case, the Black and White "call", which says

> *Open Call for artist on the theme "Black & White". The mediums acceptable are: painting, drawing photography,  digital art and collage.*

has 4 restrictions: age (must be 18 and over), the artwork must not be older than 3 years, artwork must be of a black & white theme, and a particular set of acceptable mediums. But as you can see, there are no restrictions on the subject, on what you want to draw, experience, or where you are from.

The way "artistic open call" is used [here](https://www.florencecontemporary.com/open-call) seems like it is very particular to a certain group of people. I personally think "call" here is an artistic argot.